# Jquery mobile loses custom style after button text changed

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a simple (newbie here) task in jquery mobile.  Change the text of a button which has a custom style applied.  I can change the text without problem in the 'pageinit' event however I lose the custom style in the process.  Have read lots of article in stackoverflow but still lack a working solution.

Excerpt of html page below loaded by ajax

CSS

```html
#goal .ui-btn-inner   {
    text-align: center;
    background: chartreuse;
    ui-disabled: true;
}
```

Button to be styled

```html
<div data-corners="false" data-role="controlgroup" >
  <a href="#" data-role="button" id="goal" >
   text to be changed
  </a>
</div>
...
```

Here is the jquery mobile code that changes the button text.

```js
$(document).delegate('#problem_screen', 'pageinit', function() {
  $('#goal').on('click', function() {
    console.log('goal clicked');
  });
  $('#goal .ui-btn-text').text('New button text');
});
```

Thanks

Comment: how does it lose  style? can you provide a snapshot? looks fine here, text is changed on button click http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/xWNcS/

Comment: Ross:  When I try that I get "Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'". Maybe the refresh has to be done elsewhere.

Comment: Omar: The problem lies with the ajax transition to the page.  After I hook the pageinit event jqm seems to apply its regular button style and I lose my custom styling.  If you run the page 'standalone' it works fine.

Comment: Then add `data-role=none` to the button or end each css property with `!important`.

Comment: Omar: Tried both suggestions and neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this to work.  My first JQM mistake was to define custom styles on each page of the multiple page application.  This is wrong -- you must define all your custom styles in one location, typically a style sheet file which is included by every page.  Another mistake is to have same id value on different pages.  Wrong -- id values must be unique throughout application.

The api that applies (in this case enhances a style) is .addClass(").  In my case I defined a style as follows:

```
.goal-style {
 text-align: center;
 background: charteuse;
 ui-disabled: true;
}
```

Now after I update the button's text I say:

```
$('#goal').addClass('goal-style');  // Note: do not use '.goal-style'
```